# Getting Response Code as 500 when hitting Rest API in Python

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, salesforce

I am using requests.get() to invoke the REST api. When i hardcode the URL it is working fine but if i append the account name with URL getting the response code as 500. Please help.

```
    header = {'Authorization': token_type + " " + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    account_name="test_account"
    uri = "https://my_instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/account/entitlement?AccountName="+account_name
    user_create_res = requests.get(uri, headers=header)
```

but same code is working when i give,

```
header = {'Authorization': token_type + " " + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
uri = "https://my_instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/account/entitlement?AccountName=test_account"
user_create_res = requests.get(uri, headers=header)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the account_name variable using

```
print(account_name)
```

Make sure the text logged in the console is the same as the name you tried hard coding.

---

Though it could also be that the account_name variable is not a String.

---

### I can not say for sure if I don't get more info like where you define the account_name variable.